# VBA check cell column for letters and displays a word in corresponding cell

Tags: excel, vba

```
 Option Explicit

 Sub PartNumberIdentifier()
```

Defining variables here

```
 Dim cell As Range
 Dim celltxt As String
```

I have a range in my excel sheet called firstDigit that displays 256 rows within a column. I want to check the column to see if it contains a letter

```
 For Each cell In Range("firstDigit")
 If cell >= "A" And cell <= "Z" Then
 ActiveSheet.Range("D4:D259") = "Ours"
 Else
 ActiveSheet.Range("D4:D259") = "NO"
```

When executing, the code just writes Ours in D4:D259 all the way down regardless of whether the column corresponding in firstDigit is a letter or not.

```
 End If
 Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: What column is `firstDigit` in? You need to write to one cell, not the entire column. Your column value is currently showing the result of the last test since each loop overwrites the prev loops value

Comment: firstDigit is in column B4:B259 and I want the text of whether it is a letter or not within each B cell to post in column D.

Comment: Wow that worked amazing! One more thing. Since you tested it this way. How could I make the cells that you stated contains non alpha char to be colored yellow? When I do it, it colors the boxes within firstDigit

Comment: That changed the color of the boxes within firstDigit which I already tried. I wanted the boxes in column D to change yellow instead. How would I do that?

Comment: Please put your comments below on the solution where I am putting mine - I left a comment saying how to do that but will update the solution as well

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you so much for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try...

```
Sub PartNumber()

Dim xCell As Range

For Each xCell In Range("firstDigit")
    If xCell Like WorksheetFunction.Rept("[a-zA-Z]", Len(xCell)) Then
        xCell.Offset(0, 2) = "Alpha Only"
    Else
        xCell.Offset(0, 2) = "Contains non Alpha Char"
        xCell.Offset(0, 2).Interior.Color = vbYellow   'To color the cell that has string
    End If
Next xCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Updated to color code the cell in `Column B` when the string is not strictly alpha. If you want to color code your cell in `Column D`, just use the `Offset` like the line above

Comment: Updated to color cell in `Column D` instead of `Column B`

Comment: Perfect thank you for updating the code to display color in the incorrect boxes

Comment: lol I thought that was really sarcastic for a moment, but i'm guessing you mean "*in the correct boxes*"